# Traceback (most recent call last) - NameError in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and am learning through a Kaggle tutorials. In one of them around the functions section, I am typing this code.

```
def least_difference(a, b, c):
    """
    Return the smallest difference between any two numbers among a, b, & c

    """
    diff1 = abs(a - b)
    diff2 = abs(b - c)
    diff3 = abs(a - c)
    return min(diff1, diff2, diff3)


print(
    least_difference( 2, 200, 100 ),
    least_difference( 1, 10, 10 ),
    least_difference(5, 6, 7),
)
```

The tutorial is around using the help function. So when I type

`>>> help(least_difference)`

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'least_difference' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something I am missing to see the docsstring?

Comment: Did you write that code in a script, or in the interpreter? If the former, have you `import`ed it into your interpreter before running `help`? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the file into the interactive context. Use:

```
$ python -i ./relative/path/to/file.py # or python3 depending on your PATH
...
>>> help(least_difference)
Return the smallest difference between any two numbers among a, b, & c
```

Alternatively, import it directly from the REPL:

```
$ python # or python3 depending on your PATH
...
>>> import ./relative/path/to/file.py
>>> help(least_difference)
Return the smallest difference between any two numbers among a, b, & c
```